# What is the meaning of this sentence "laws to be introduced"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> There has been a stream of backlash that has caused regulation and **laws to be introduced**...

In this [video](https://youtu.be/gwzp0VTgTqM?t=122), the guy said "laws to be introduced".
Does it mean it was introduced in the past or it has to be introduced in the future?

Comment: "It has caused regulation and **laws** to be introduced." US pronunciation can make the word sound like _larz_: UK pronunciation like _lorz_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video jumps a bit at that point, which is what makes it slightly difficult to understand, but the context makes it clear that what he's saying is:

> There has been a stream of backlash, that has caused regulation and **laws** to be introduced, like GDPR...

Comment: I think I got it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It means the laws were introduced in the past.

"... that has **caused** laws to be introduced..."

"Caused" is in the past tense. This means it has already happened. If the laws were going to be introduced in the future, it might say,

"... that **is causing** laws to be introduced..."
OR
"... that **will cause** laws to be introduced..."
OR
"... that has **required that laws be introduced**..."